# ACF: data not retrieved correctly in the_loop() IF user is not the post author

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i have a loop which retrieves correctly post data, (title, etc) and works fine with ACF fields ONLY if the viewer is the post author, it is not working IF the viewer is someone else... :(

```
 public static function getFields() {
        $postID = get_the_ID();
        $fields = [];
        $array_anagrafica = [];
        if( have_rows('anagrafica', $postID) ) { // <<- it's not working even with no $postID
            while (have_rows('anagrafica', $postID)) {
                the_row();

                $array_anagrafica['cf'] = get_sub_field('codice_fiscale');
                $array_anagrafica['piva'] = get_sub_field('partita_iva');
```

any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a matter of acf_form -> using acf_form() toghether with acf_form_head() replicates backend form and can then be properly initated.